# python - asyncio, ppadb - synchronous await implementation is 10 times slower

Tags: python, adb, python-asyncio

Trying to get few screenshots from a phone using `ppadb` and came across weird behavior. The synchronous implementation using asynchronous programming is 10x slower than simple synchronous implementation.

```py
import asyncio, subprocess, time
from ppadb.client_async import ClientAsync
from ppadb.client import Client

def startServer():
    subprocess.run("adb start-server", stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
startServer()

async def doScreen(device, i):
    await device.screencap()
    print(i, " ", sep="", end="")

async def main():
    adb = (Client(host="localhost", port=5037), ClientAsync(host="localhost", port=5037))
    device = (adb[0].devices()[0], (await adb[1].devices())[0])
    
    n = 30
    
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(n):
        device[0].screencap()
        print(i, " ", sep="", end="")
    print("\nsynchronous ", (time.time() - start)/n, "\n", sep="")
    
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(n):
        await device[1].screencap()
        print(i, " ", sep="", end="")
    print("\nsynchronous using await ", (time.time() - start)/n, "\n", sep="")
    
    start = time.time()
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        for i in range(n):
            tg.create_task(doScreen(device[1], i))
    print("\nasynchronous and parallel ", (time.time() - start)/n, "\n", sep="")
asyncio.run(main())
```

output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
synchronous 0.22747948964436848

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
synchronous using await 2.2235145966211953

0 7 11 5 10 16 26 29 1 15 9 28 12 17 14 2 19 13 6 21 4 22 18 8 3 25 23 20 27 24 
asynchronous and parallel 0.16928408145904542
```

I would expect some slowdown due to asynchronous overhead, but slowdown of ~2 seconds per operation seems too high.

I would like to ask what does cause this huge slowdown.